# Calculate the maximization of expectation for the power of dot product

Tags: optimization, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose the random vector $\mathbf{v}=[e^{j\theta_1},e^{j\theta_2},\cdots,e^{j\theta_N}]^T$ with $\theta_n \sim U(0,2\pi)$. Then, for $p\in \{1,2,\cdots\}$, what is the maximal of the following expectation?
\begin{align}
\max \mathbb{E} \left[\left|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{v} \right|^{2p}\right] \text{subject to}~ x_n\ge0, \|\mathbf{x} \|_2=1 
\end{align}

---

I have the guess that when the entries in $\mathbf{x}$ are equivalent, the objective above can be maximized. But how can we prove it? My efforts are
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[\left|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{v} \right|^{2p}\right] &= \mathbb{E} \left[(x_1v_1+\cdots+x_N v_N)(x_1v_1^*+\cdots+x_Nv_N^*) \cdots(x_1v_1^*+\cdots+x_Nv_N^*)\right]\\
\end{align}
Because of the randomness of $v_n$, only the squared terms are remained, i.e., $x_n^{2k}$, where $k$ is an integer. But I do not know how to continue.

Comment: It looks like $x$ constrained to the positive orthant of a hyper-sphere centered at the origin. So intuitively id try to make $x$ align with the expected value of $v$. If $v$ weren’t random then setting $x=v$ would be the optimal solution.